# OOD for Reporting errors after handling user's request in Service Layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, soa, object-oriented-analysis

I believe there are 2 types of error that can occur during a user's request.

**{1}**: system error (exception, fatal error, warning, notice, etc)   
**{2}**: user control error (what the user has done wrong, usually occur during validation)

Usually reporting **{1}** is relatively simple. Most people would just display an error page or notification. The **{2}** case is different.

Yii and Rails and some other frameworks offer a validation scheme where you can specify validators for each attribute in a model. During the validation, the validators will validate the specified attributes and report errors in a map form: *attributeName => array of errors.*

In an application, a service in **[Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)** may depend other services' logic and domain models' logic so its set of attributes and validation may also depend on these foreign services and domain models.

For example, User Registration Service owns the attributes "username" and "password" and its logic rules may depend on User's logic rules in validating username max length and password max length.

So my question is, how do we validate these attributes through many layers of dependency and report the errors back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that difficult. Most of the model validation errors you can handle on the client side using some form of client side validation. for example you can use the **client_side_validation** gem for that. You can render those errors as notice or alerts also as follws

```
@user.errors.full_messages.join('. ')
```

Now coming back to your question, you can have multiple layers of exception handling. The preference of the layers depend on the functionality you are implementing. for example while creating a new user first thing you will check is data validity. Also you can have application wide exception handlers and each of these exception handlers can have there `own error reporting mechanisms`. So it just depends on the scenario.

Comment: Since Model validation errors are not Exception, I think using an Exception Handler is not feasible in this situation.

Comment: Exactly, So for your registration system while registering the user the emphasis will be on user data validations and while signing in the user the emphasis should be on authenticating the user. There is no need to check  username or password validations.

Comment: In the registration system, we do have to validate username max length, useremail max length, password max length,etc. to ensure it complies with the database settings, so the registration system will have to ask either the domain model or data mapper for these validations. I was hesitating in deciding whether the service has to import the validations from these foreign objects or let them validate and bubble up the errors.